# Merge two forms with two radio button and one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

So I have this two forms. Each has its own action, separate fields and values, radio button and button. What I want to do is that I want to have two radio buttons and one button. What is the best solution.

```
<div class="span6">
      <h2 class="headback" >انتخاب دروازه پرداخت</h2>
      <div class="text-box" style="padding-bottom: 0px">

        <form class="form-inline" method="post" id="PaymentForm" action="https://google.com" style="direction: rtl">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{payment.Amount}}"/>
          <input type='hidden' name='paymentId' value='{{payment.InvoiceNumber}}' />
          <input type='hidden' name='revertURL' value='http://test2.happycard.ir/payment/verify' />
          <input type='hidden' name='customerId' value='{{payment.Id}}' />

          <label class="radio">
            <img src="/media/images/images/bank.jpg"/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="PaymentProvider" id="PaymentProvider" value="4" checked>
          </label>
          <ul style="text-align: right">
            <li>
              <input type="button" value="Proceed" ng-click="SetPrePayment();" class="btn btn-primary">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form >


    <form class="form-inline" method="post" id="PaymentForm2" action="www.wikipedia.com" style="direction: rtl">
          <input type="hidden" name="pin"         value='5I8bpgGr034AmB38MPQ7'/>
          <input type="hidden" name="Id"            value="{{payment.Id}}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="OrderId"     value="{{payment.OrderId}}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="amount"        value="{{payment.Amount}}"/>
          <input type='hidden' name='paymentId'     value='{{payment.InvoiceNumber}}' />
          <?php if(custom_config::$IPGtest==1){ ?>
          <input type='hidden' name='revertURL'   value="<?php echo custom_config::$Test2ParsianRevertUrlHappyBarg; ?>" />
          <?php } elseif(custom_config::$IPGtest==2){ ?>
          <input type='hidden' name='revertURL'   value="<?php echo custom_config::$ParsianRevertUrlHappyBarg; ?>" />
          <?php } ?>

          <label class="radio">
            <img src="/media/images/images/bank.jpg"/><br/>
            <input type="radio" value="parsian" name="bankname" checked>
          </label>

          <ul style="text-align: right">
            <li>
              <input  type="button" ng-click="SetPrePayment2();" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-primary">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form >        
  </div>
</div>
```

Spoiler alert, AngularJS is used in button's actions. I uploaded a photo to show you the output of my current code.

[image]

What I want to be like is:

[image]

This is the code for my SetPrePayment() function.

```
$scope.SetPrePayment=function(){
      $http.post('/payment/happy_payment_register/',{ 'Amount':$scope.totalPrice,'Item':$scope.item.Id, 'Description':$scope.item.Title, 'Count':$scope.defaultQuantity })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          if(data!='Fail')
          {
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.payment=data;
              timer= $timeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("PaymentForm").submit();
              },10)
            }, 0);
          }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data)
        });
    };
```

and SetPrePayment2() is :

```
$scope.SetPrePayment=function(){
      $http.post('/payment/happy_payment_register/',{ 'Amount':$scope.totalPrice,'Item':$scope.item.Id, 'Description':$scope.item.Title, 'OrderId':$scope.item.Id, 'Count':$scope.defaultQuantity })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          if(data!='Fail')
          {
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.payment=data;
              timer= $timeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("PaymentForm2").submit();
              },10)
            }, 0);
          }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data)
        });
    };
```

Comment: Your question does not make any sense , explain more

Comment: You see there are two buttons, right? I want to have one button and two radio buttons. Based on the user selection, the respective form will be called by pressing the button!
Need more explanation?!

Comment: I think you are wanting a different form to show based on which radio button is selected?

Comment: I edited my question to reduce the ambiguity of my question for you guys

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery for solve this problem.

move your button, out of two forms and set an ID for that.

`<button id="myButton">Submit</button>`

now you can check radio buttons in jquery to submit own form.

jQuery sample code:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( '#myButton' ).on( 'click', function() {

        if ( $( '#radio_1' ).is(':checked') ) {

            $( '#form_1' ).submit();
            setPrePayment();


        } else { 

            $( '#form_2' ).submit();
            setPrePayment2();

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Dear Mohammad, thanks for your effort, but each button has their own methods to call.

Comment: The first one calls setPrePayment and the second one calls setPrePayment2.

Comment: Yor wellcome. so what is this different of these functions?

Comment: They are totally different. Their names, well, they look the same. setPrePayment fucntion uses the first form id and setPrePayment uses the second form id.

Comment: Your code seems fine but when I put it, the buttons didn't do anything .... this is how I impelement it:
$(document).ready({  

    $( '#buttonId' ).on( 'click', function() {

        if ( $( '#PaymentProvider' ).is(':checked') ) {

            $( '#PaymentProvider' ).submit();
            SetPrePayment();


        } else { 

            $( '#PaymentProvider2' ).submit();
            SetPrePayment2();

        }

    });

});

Comment: oh sorry, my start of jquery is wrong, i edited . please recheck now :)

Comment: my log says: SetPrePayment2() is undefined. I guess the way you put it in JQuery is wrong. shall we put it that way? I mean don't we need to use {{}}  or something?

Comment: Please change **s**etPrePayment2 to **S**etPrePayment and check that.

Comment: Oon kar ro ham kardam Mohammad jan, hamchenan hamune!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90930/discussion-between-mohammad-yekta-and-sean).

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no jQuery needed for this. You can use `ng-if` that shows the form based on the user selection expression.

If you need to load the template conditionally you could also use `ng-include` but it should be OK with `ngIf`.

I've added two controllers one for each form that's only needed if you have to do many things in the form or you want to have them separate.
But the same approach with `ng-if` will work with one form controller.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/m9k5p5h3/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('FormOneController', FormOneController)
 .controller('FormTwoController', FormTwoController)
 .controller('MainController', MainController);

function FormOneController($window) {
    this.submit = function() {
     $window.alert('hello from form 1');
    }
}

function FormTwoController($window) {
    this.submit = function() {
        $window.alert('hello from form 2');
    }
}

function MainController() {
 var vm = this;
    
   
    vm.hideForms = hideForms;
    vm.forms = getFormObject();
    vm.isFormActive = isFormActive;
    vm.selectForm = selectForm;
    vm.showForm = showForm;
    
    activate();
    
    function activate() {
     vm.selectedForm = vm.forms[0];
    }
    
    function getFormObject() {
     return [{
            id: 1,
         name: 'form1',
            label: 'show form 1',
            visible: false
        }, {
            id: 2,
         name: 'form2',
            label: 'show form 2',
            visible: false
        }];
    }
    
    function hideForms() {
     angular.forEach(vm.forms, function(form) {
         form.visible = false;
        });
        //console.log(vm.forms);
    }
    
    function isFormActive(id) {
     return vm.selectedForm.id === id && vm.selectedForm.visible
    }
    
    function selectForm(form) {
        hideForms();
     vm.selectedForm = form;
    }
    
    function showForm() {
     vm.selectedForm.visible = true;
        //console.log(vm.selectedForm);
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="form in mainCtrl.forms">{{form.name}}
    <input type="radio" name="formSelector" value="form" ng-click="mainCtrl.selectForm(form)" ng-checked="mainCtrl.selectedForm === form"></input></label>
    <button ng-click="mainCtrl.showForm()">show form</button>

    <form ng-if="mainCtrl.isFormActive(1)" ng-controller="FormOneController as formOneCtrl">
            <button ng-click="formOneCtrl.submit()">form1 submit</button>
        </form>

        <form ng-if="mainCtrl.isFormActive(2)" ng-controller="FormTwoController as formTwoCtrl">
            <button ng-click="formTwoCtrl.submit()">form2 submit</button>
        </form>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I'm new to angularjs, is there anyway you can hook me up with my code? Cause your way seems good, but it's just me that can't handle it properly.

Comment: Yes, I probably could but you haven't added your javascript code in your question. You could add your js then I can try to help.

Comment: I updated my question with codes you wanted!
The other part of javascript I used is what Mohammad suggested.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your forms. Please explain what you're trying to do. Do you want to fill both froms and then submit the form? Or do you want to fill the first form and then pull the data for the second form? (Couldn't follow your chat with Mohammad because of the language.)

Comment: No, only the selected form (by the radio button) will be sent. The other one remains as it is.

Comment: OK, I'm not updating my answer because I think it should be enough to understand how the form switching works. If not please let me know then I can add more explanation. You should use `ng-model` for your inputs and remove the `$timeouts` from your functions `setPrePayment` because these are already your functions responsible for posting the data. (So there's no need to call submit of form.) Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/fxaa3kct/).

Comment: I really appreciate all your efforts! I managed to it in another way. But +1 for you for your concern.
Thanks again mate